# Retrieving app request receiver's Facebook ID

Tags: facebook

If my Facebook app knows that an app user (FB ID = foo) has sent an app request (request ID = bar) to another FB user (user2), is there a way to find the FB ID of user2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this should be available prior to authentication of *user2*.

But there is some edge case:

If this is a request which involves only one recipient, you know the `id` of that request (it's passed to your canvas once user accepting it in `request_ids` URL argument) and don't mind using application's `access_token` this is pretty easy.

Just get the details of request from Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/REQUEST_ID?access_token=APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Result will include all the request details including recipients list.

Beware, this method allow you to know to whom request was sent but it's not allow you to ensure that visitor is the same person (it takes nothing to fake request accept if someone know request `id`).

BTW, `APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN` may be either one described in [Authenticating as an App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) or an older `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` format...